# Why is this sort result intermittent?

Tags: javascript

This code is designed to create a simple array of random numbers with no duplication.  When I run this code, the result is sorted only intermittently.  About 30-40% of the time, the result for numberStack is not sorted

```
let maxNumber = 100;
let totalNumbers = 10;
let stack = {};
let numberStack = [];

for (let i=0;i<=totalNumbers;i++) {
    let r = parseInt(Math.random(1) * maxNumber);
    stack[r] = 1;
}

numberStack = Object.keys(stack);
numberStack.sort((a,b) => {a-b}); 

console.log(numberStack);
```

I would expect numberStack to be a sorted array of numbers every time.

Comment: Your callback doesn't *return* anything...

Comment: Either `=> { return a - b }` or `=> a - b` ['Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Comment: To clarify the point, if your arrow function was converted into a plain function,.  `function (a,b) { a-b; }`  Basically your subtract a number from another number, that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I definitely missed that.  Upon changing to `return a-b;` the functionality worked as expected.  Why is my question downvoted? Did I do something wrong by asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s probably the chance of having 10 numbers in order with the 30% to 40% you mention.

Remove the curly braces from the sort callback function (so after the fat arrow) to make it return something.